# Fixed div transparency

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap layout with **navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top** it appends **sticky** and **margin-top** after 140px scroll. I am unable to make the sticky/navbar div transparent with the background-image. For some reason, it just appears to have a white background.

Is there a fix I can apply?

https://codepen.io/gza/pen/wqzBeN

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navgation">
```

After

Comment: Can you also point out the issue in a screenshot. Not sure if i understand your question.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood, but is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/PKGNrz

Comment: The class `nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top.sticky` adds the css `background-image` whereas `.navbar-inverse` only has `background-color`

Comment: Why are you using a *prefixed* gradient for the `background-image` of the navbar instead of just using `background` with an RGBA value?

Comment: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvRrKg](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvRrKg)

Answer (score 0):

If you set .navbar to position:fixed from the start rather than on scroll it will appear on top of the background.

The issue is that it is appearing as as a sibling element to your background, once it is fixed it will be allowed to display on top of it. You can remove the function in javascript that changes it to position fixed on scroll and just add the new css property in for .navbar.